# Like we share data(text/file/IMG) to WhatsApp in android can we do same for desktop WhatsApp app?

Tags: javascript, electron, whatsapp

I am developing a desktop app in that I have to share some data(invoice detail text/IMG/pdf) via WhatsApp.
I know there is no open-source API for WhatsApp for sending data.

we can share data with WhatsApp like below in android.

```
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Application of social rating share with your friend");
        try {
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).startActivity(whatsappIntent);
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp")));
        }
```

1. can we do the same for the desktop WhatsApp app or web.whatsapp?
2. if possible can anyone share sample code for the same?
3. what is the limitation of this approach?